# Maclaurin series stuck at finding $L_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I need to develop Maclaurin serie of $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

I found all the derivative, and all the zero values for the derivatives. I come up with that :

$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+\frac{6}{2!}x^2+\frac{24}{3!}x^3+\frac{120}{4!}x^4+...+\frac{?}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1} + ...$

Now I want to determinate $L_n=\frac{f^{n-1}(0)}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}$

And this is where I'm stuck. How can I calculate $L_n$ ?

Comment: Note that $6/2! = 3$, $24/3! = 4$, $120/4!=5$, etc. Do you see a pattern? Can you prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calculating successive derivatives, sometimes it is more illuminating to *not* simplify out the entire calculation:  $$\begin{align*} f(x) &= (1-x)^{-2}, \\ f'(x) &= 2(1-x)^{-3}, \\ f''(x) &= 2(3)(1-x)^{-4}, \\ f'''(x) &= 2(3)(4)(1-x)^{-5}, \\ f^{(4)}(x) &= 2(3)(4)(5)(1-x)^{-6}, \\ &\vdots \\ f^{(n)}(x) &= \ldots. \end{align*}$$  Does the pattern seem more evident now?

Comment: Well I guess it would be $n!(1-x)^{-n-1}$ ?

Comment: No that formula is not consistent with what the first several cases indicate:  for instance, $f^{(4)}(x) = 2(3)(4)(5)(1-x)^{-6}$, but according to your formula, it would be $4!(1-x)^{-5}.$  So you seem to be off by one.

Comment: Then $(n+1)!(1-x)^{-n}$ ... However I need to find $f^{n-1}$ not $f^{-n}$

Comment: That's still not correct; it should be $f^{(n)}(x) = (n+1)!(1-x)^{-n-2}$.  But in any case, use the appropriate formula for $f^{(n-1)}(x)$, from which you should find $L_n = nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: But since x is always 0 it won't works ?

Comment: We agree that $f^{(n-1)}(x) = n!(1-x)^{-n-1}$, yes?  And we also agree that $$L_n = \frac{f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1},$$ right?  So $f^{(n-1)}(0) = n!$ from the first formula.  Then $L_n = \dfrac{n!}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} = nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: Finally I understand... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the geometric series $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^{n}} $$
add differentiate it:$$
\frac{d}{dx}{\left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right)}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{nx^{n-1}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{ 1 }{ 1-x }=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+...\\\frac{ 1 }{ 1-x }\frac{ 1 }{ 1-x }=\\(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+...)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+...)\\\\=1+(x+x)+(x^2+x^2+xx)+(x^3+x^3+x^2x+xx^2)+...=\\\\1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+6x^5+... $$